# Generate a decision tree given a set of rules

Tags: algorithm, decision-tree

in the last few days I've been thinking about this problem without finding an optimal solution, hence this question.

Let's say we have a set of N variables, which a user can compose to create a list of rules and the following action, such as:

```
variables V_1,V_2,V_3
V_1 > 5 -> "Turn left"
V_2 < 6 -> "Turn right"
1 < V_1 < 4 -> "Continue straight"
V_1 = 0 AND V_2 > 6 AND V3 > 5 -> "Go backwards"
default -> "Stay"
```

Variables won't necessarly be integers, and suppose that the rules are all composed by a list of AND clauses followed by an action.

What i want to do is to build a decision tree that would allow me to fast process an input like (0,7,9) and return the proper action.
As of now, my only idea is to partition the variable space and the see where the input state fits, but it seems a slow soluition : anybody knows something that may be faster?

Comment: The problem definition doesn't seem clear. For example, if `V_1 == 3` it fits two rules, `Turn left` and `Continue straight` which seem contradicting.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote the example quickly and i messed up with that rule. I'll correct it in a second.

Comment: how big is the variable space?

Comment: It's mostly user dependant, but I think that 10 variables is a good approximation. the "smallest" variable can take 5 values, the , the wider a random subset of a 52x52 space.

Comment: Are the rules always inequalities on single variables or equalities on multiple variables, or can you have arbitrary linear constraints?  Or even nonlinear?

Comment: The rules are an indefinite sequence of AND clauses, and each clause can be one of {=,!=,<,>, "in"} condition ( n<x<m can be seen as n<x and x<m), while is indicates the appartenence to a set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes it slow? Lot of rules? Long rules? Lot of variables? Slow rules processing?

If you have not to many <del>variables</del> **rules**, I would clearly go for a hash table.

This is an example of tree (not necessarily optimal) for the problem you stated.

```
variables V_1,V_2,V_3
V_1 > 5 -> "Turn left"
V_2 < 6 -> "Turn right"
1 < V_1 < 4 -> "Continue straight"
V_1 = 0 AND V_2 > 6 AND V3 > 5 -> "Go backwards"
default -> "Stay"

   V1         V2      V3
   <0 ------- <6 --------------- Right
              >=6 -------------- Stay

   0 -------- <6 --------------- Right
               6 --------------- Stay
              >6 ---- <=5 ------ Stay
                      >5 ------- Backwards

   ]0-1] ---- <6 --------------- Right
              >=6 -------------- Stay

   ]1-4[ ----------------------- Straight

   [4-5] ---- <6 --------------- Right
              >=6 -------------- Stay

   >5 ------- <6 --------------- Right
              >=6 -------------- Stay
```

Comment: There won't be many variables but the wider one can assude tons of values. The point is, most of the input will result in the default action, ( think of it as a sparse matrix), and I don't know how to use that: decision trees seemed a good idea, but building them with user defined intervals is a mess

Comment: You can use a range-tree to efficiently search across intervals. The decision tree is very efficient but as you can see in my example, there is some kind of redundancy.

Comment: The rules shouldn't be less than 400, and I fear an hash table would use too much memory.